# How do I remove the white bar under the content on 1440p monitors?

Tags: css, html, sass, grid

[image]
I am exploring CSS Grid and I am having trouble because the size doesn't use full height and my HTML and body is [width, height 100%]. I have a large white section how do I make it snap to whatever is top?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Here is my CSS.

```
*,** {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html{
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.grid {
margin: 0;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 100%;
grid-template-rows: repeat(auto, 4);
/* grid-template-rows: 13% auto 20%; */
grid-template-areas:
"header" 
"main";

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-rows:   repeat(auto, 3);

    grid-template-areas: 
    "header header"
    "main main"
    "main main";
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    grid-template-columns: 30% auto;
    grid-template-rows:   repeat(auto, 3);

    grid-template-areas: 
    "header header"
    "sidebar main"
    "sidebar2 main";
}
```

A concern is if I mess with positions it makes things fly left...

Comment: What if you set body height: `body{height:100vh}` and container to either 100vh or 100%?

Comment: @JakubMuda if i do body 100vh there is white space between header and main

Answer (score 0):

You can use vh units, calc and min-height like:

```
header { grid-area: header; height: 80px; }
nav    { grid-area: sidebar;  }
main   { grid-area: main; min-height: calc(100vh - 80px); } /* subtract header height */
aside  { grid-area: sidebar2; }
```

Here is an example (I've changed the sizes a bit to work on stackoverflow):

```css
*, ** {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.grid {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto, 4);
  /* grid-template-rows: 13% auto 20%; */
  grid-template-areas: "header"  "main";
}
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto, 3);
    grid-template-areas: "header header" "main main" "main main";
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 30% auto;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto, 3);
    grid-template-areas: "header header" "sidebar main" "sidebar2 main";
  }
}

header {
  background: tomato;
  grid-area: header;
  height: 40px;
}

nav {
  background: gold;
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

main {
  background: olive;
  grid-area: main;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 40px);
}

aside {
  background: orange;
  grid-area: sidebar2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <header>Header</header>
  <nav>Sidebar</nav>
  <main>Main</main>
  <aside>Sidebar 2</aside>
</div>
```